# What does "Sanc..." mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, language-explanation, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Dr. Strange rescues America Chavez from [Gargantos](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Gargantos). Afterwards, he and Wong
each ask her a different question:

> Dr Strange: Hey, kid. What did that creature want with you?
>
> Wong: Where're your parents?

Dr Strange tries to open a portal:

> Dr Strange: We'll take her back to the **Sanc...**

Then America Chavez runs away.

What does "Sanc..." mean?

Comment: "We'll take her back to the Sanctum."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe *'Sanc.'* refers to the *Sanctum Sanctorum*, which is the townhouse in New York City that serves as the headquarters for the Masters of the Mystic Arts, and also where Dr Strange and sometimes Wong, live.